# How to fix "debian-rules-is-dh_make-template"?

Tags: makefile, packaging, lintian

## Problem

I had a following error(`debian-rules-is-dh_make-template`) from `lintian`.

How should I fix to pass the error?

The message showed me that I didn't modify `debian/rules`, but I already modified (I added `override_dh_auto_clean:`), so I guess that my `debian/rules` is insufficient but I can't figure out why my `debian/rules` is insufficient...

```
$ lintian hello_2.10-0ubuntu1.dsc --info
...
E: hello source: debian-rules-is-dh_make-template
N:
N:    The debian/rules file appears to be an unmodified or insufficiently
N:    modified copy of the dh_make template.
N:
N:    Please double-check the rules file.
N:
N:    Severity: important, Certainty: certain
N:
N:    Check: rules, Type: source
N:
...
```

my `dibian/rules` is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# See debhelper(7) (uncomment to enable)
# output every command that modifies files on the build system.
#export DH_VERBOSE = 1


# see FEATURE AREAS in dpkg-buildflags(1)
#export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all

# see ENVIRONMENT in dpkg-buildflags(1)
# package maintainers to append CFLAGS
#export DEB_CFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND  = -Wall -pedantic
# package maintainers to append LDFLAGS
#export DEB_LDFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND = -Wl,--as-needed


%:
        dh $@

override_dh_auto_clean:
        echo clean

# dh_make generated override targets
# This is example for Cmake (See https://bugs.debian.org/641051 )
#override_dh_auto_configure:
#       dh_auto_configure -- #  -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)
```

## Background

I'm trying to do the tutorial(https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html#starting-a-package).

By using default `debian/rules`, I had a error like this(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-packaging-guide/+bug/1248353/).

Therefore, I added `override_dh_auto_clean:` in my `debian/rules` for workaround(https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-packaging-guide/+bug/1248353/comments/10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about delete commentary in `debian/rules`?

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@

override_dh_auto_clean:
        echo clean
```